# In a book we have lines or rows

Tags: image-identification

Each one of the number level is called **line** or **row**?

For instance if I want to guide a person to look at certain sentence which is located in the level of number 4 "The grammar of English consists of all the rules etc.".

> "Please, Look at the line / row 4."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is text, then you use **line**.

> Finally, it introduced a standard system of reference, "through line numbering," based on the lines printed in the 1623 edition ... (Description of Norton Facsimile edition of Shakespeare).

If it's a table such as in a spreadsheet, or some kind of diagram, you use **row**.

> The seven rows of the table, called periods, ... ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table))